# Search and replace pattern for such a case

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a solution for the following case:

original text:

```
= This is the first line =
= This is the first line again
== This is the second line ==
=== This is the third line ===
==== This is the forth line ====
==== The tailing '='s are optional, but if they're present, should be removed
```

expected result:

```
h1. This is the first line
h1. This is the first line again
h2. This is the second line
h3. This is the third line
h4. This is the forth line
h4. The tailing '='s are optional, but if they're present, should be removed
```

any language is ok (python, perl, bash is better).

Comment: You just need markdown parser

Comment: what do you mean 'markdown parser'? Actually I tried to find tools to translate such format of text (similar to wiki) to markdown, but haven't find a good tool, now I just want to translate such lines to markdown format in my own script and has no idea on it by now.

Answer (score 0):

Through Python.

```
import re
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:                                   # Open the text file for reading
    for line in f:                                                  # iterate through all the lines  
        if line.startswith('='):                                    # Do the below operation only on the lines which starts with `=` symbol.
            finalcount = line.split()[0].count('=')                 # Count the number of `=` symbols located on the first word only.
            line = re.sub(r'=+$', r'', line)                        # Remove all the trailing `=` symbols if it's presented.
            line = re.sub(r'^\S+', r'h'+str(finalcount)+'.', line)  # Replace the first word in the lines which startswith `=` with `h` plus the value stores in finalcount variable plus a dot. 
            print(line, end='')                                     # Now print the modified line.
```

**Output:**

```
h1. This is the first line 
h1. This is the first line again
h2. This is the second line 
h3. This is the third line 
h4. This is the forth line 
h4. The tailing '='s are optional, but if they're present, should be removed
```